# Difference of a Timestamp

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I have for `NewTimeSecond` the current timestamp in HH:MM:SS format, which is counted by a timer and for `RWTime = "14:42:00"` also in HH:MM:SS format. but somehow i dont get the result

```
console.log("calc");
var time1ms = new Date(NewTimeSecond).getTime;              
var time2ms = new Date(RWTime).getTime;                     
console.log(time1ms);
console.log(time2ms);

var res = Math.abs(time1ms - time2ms) / 1000;
```

for `console.log(time1ms)` and `console.log(time2ms)` i get 
`ƒ getTime() { [native code] }` in my console

Comment: `getTime` is a function, so you need to call it like this `getTime()`

Comment: now i get NaN as result

Comment: See my answer below

Answer (score 1):

What `ƒ getTime() { [native code] }` is saying, is that `getTime` is a function, so `time1ms` and `time2ms` are both assigned the getTime function *rather than the result* of that function. To call the function, you use parenthesis `()` much like you do with `console.log` and `Math.abs`

The `getTime` function does not take any parameters so you just call it will empty parenthesis

```
console.log("calc");
var time1ms = new Date(NewTimeSecond).getTime();              
var time2ms = new Date(RWTime).getTime();                     
console.log(time1ms);
console.log(time2ms);

var res = Math.abs(time1ms - time2ms) / 1000;
```

However, passing a 24-hour time only to the date constructor will not work, because the native date object does not parse it correctly, and they will be invalid dates.

You can however, add a date part to the string, which will allow date to parse it correctly.

```
console.log("calc");
let NewTimeSecond = '10:20:30';
let RWTime = '14:42:00';

let someDate = '2019-01-01';

NewTimeSecond = `${someDate}T${NewTimeSecond}`; // Creates the string `2019-01-01T10:20:30'
RWTime = `${someDate}T${RWTime}`; // Creates the string `2019-01-01T14:42:00'

var time1ms = new Date(NewTimeSecond).getTime();              
var time2ms = new Date(RWTime).getTime();                     
console.log(time1ms);
console.log(time2ms);
```